# Boost Spirit Qi storing into std::vector using repeat leads to ambiguous class template instantiation

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

Storing the result of a repeat statement into a std::vector leads to compile error:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:172:12: error: ambiguous 

    class template instantiation for ‘struct boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_through_container_base<std::vector<Vertex3d<float> >, Vertex3d<float>, Vertex3d<float>, mpl_::bool_<false>, void>’

/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:103:12: error: candidates are: struct boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_through_container_base<Container, ValueType, Attribute, Sequence, typename boost::enable_if<boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence<Attribute> >::type>
     struct pass_through_container_base<Container, ValueType, Attribute
            ^
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:136:12: error:                 struct boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_through_container_base<Container, ValueType, Attribute, Sequence, typename boost::enable_if<boost::spirit::traits::is_container<T2> >::type>
     struct pass_through_container_base<
            ^
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:172:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_through_container_base<std::vector<wc3lib::Vertex3d<float> >, wc3lib::Vertex3d<float>, wc3lib::Vertex3d<float>, mpl_::bool_<false>, void>’
     struct pass_through_container
            ^
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/pass_container.hpp:50:12: error: declaration of ‘struct boost::spirit::qi::detail::pass_through_container_base<std::vector<wc3lib::Vertex3d<float> >, wc3lib::Vertex3d<float>, wc3lib::Vertex3d<float>, mpl_::bool_<false>, void>’
     struct pass_through_container_base
```

The following code is used for the grammar:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, long32(), Skipper> integer_literal;
qi::rule<Iterator, float32(), Skipper> real_literal;
qi::rule<Iterator, VertexReal3d(), Skipper> vertex_real_3d;
qi::rule<Iterator, Geoset::Vertices(), Skipper, qi::locals<long32> > vertices;


integer_literal %=
        lexeme[
            qi::int_parser<long32>()
        ]
    ;

real_literal %=
        lexeme[
            qi::real_parser<float32>()
        ]
    ;

vertex_real_3d =
        lit('{')
        >> real_literal[at_c<0>(_val) = _1]
        >> lit(',')
        >> real_literal[at_c<1>(_val) = _1]
        >> lit(',')
        >> real_literal[at_c<2>(_val) = _1]
        >> lit('}')
    ;

vertices =
        lit("Vertices")
        >> integer_literal[_a = _1]
        >> lit('{')
        >> repeat(_a)[
            vertex_real_3d
            >> lit(',')
        ][_val = _1] // Does not work?
        >> lit('}')
    ;

...

typedef Vertex3d<float32> VertexData;
typedef VertexData VertexReal3d;
typedef std::vector<VertexData> Vertices;

...

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT(
    wc3lib::mdlx::VertexData,
    (wc3lib::float32, wc3lib::float32, obj[0], obj[0] = val)
    (wc3lib::float32, wc3lib::float32, obj[1], obj[1] = val)
    (wc3lib::float32, wc3lib::float32, obj[2], obj[2] = val)
)

...

template<typename T, typename std::size_t N>
class BasicVertex : public std::array<T, N>
{
    public:
        typedef std::array<T, N> Base;

        BasicVertex() : Base()
        {
        }

        BasicVertex(const BasicVertex<T, N> &other) : Base(other) {
    }


};


template<typename T = float32>
class Vertex3d : public BasicVertex<T, 3>
{
    public:
        typedef BasicVertex<T, 3> Base;

        Vertex3d() : Base()
        {
        }

        Vertex3d(T x, T y, T z)
        {
            (*this)[0] = x;
            (*this)[1] = y;
            (*this)[2] = z;
        }

        Vertex3d(const Base &other) : Base(other) {
        }
};
```

The rule vertices should return a std::vector of VertexData. Therefore repeat is used to parse a fixed amount of vertices. The amount is placed as an integer value in the parsed file before the list and stored in _a.

The compile error hints that it cannot differ between "is_sequence" and "is_container". I am not an expert of Spirit, so I cannot answer what it does mean exactly.

Comment: Okay, I've been underway for 11 minutes now to make your sample self contained. And that's not because I'm slow with this. Can you do the honours next time?

Comment: I'm sorry to have wasted your time doing the wrong kind of homework. I'll come back if you improve your question so the problem is more apparent (you can look at my answer for simple ideas to make it selfcontained).

Comment: You have a struct that is adapted (`is_sequence<Vertex3d<float> >::value` is then true) and is also derived from std::array (and so it has typedefs for iterator, const_iterator, value_type and reference, making `is_container<Vertex3d<float> >::value` by default also true). Spirit expects that for a type only one of those is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with the edits, the question became viable.

Indeed with a (public) base class of `std::array<>` ***and*** Fusion adaptation at the same time (luckily¹!) Spirit cannot decide which of the attribute assignment paths is to be taken.

So fix it either by

- telling Spirit "These are not the droids you're looking for" (when it thinks for a moment that it's seeing a container):

  ```
  namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
      template <> 
      struct is_container<wc3lib::mdlx::VertexData> : mpl::false_ 
         { };
  } } }
  ```

  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9467b1984fbe19b4)**
- not (publicly) deriving from std::array

I think you may want to ask yourself what the point is of inheriting from `std::array<>` in the first place. And the way your Vertex types are defined now explicitly makes them non-POD, which means that performance is going to suffer.

Consider just

```
template <typename T, typename std::size_t N> class BasicVertex : public std::array<T,N> {
public:
    typedef std::array<T, N> Base;
};

template <typename T = float> class Vertex3d : public BasicVertex<T, 3> {
public:
    typedef BasicVertex<T, 3> Base;
};
```

or

```
template <typename T, typename std::size_t N> class BasicVertex {
public:
    std::array<T, N> data_;
};

template <typename T = float> class Vertex3d : public BasicVertex<T, 3> {
};
```

for some performance. In reality, I'd probably write

```
template <typename T = float> struct Vertex3d {
    T x, y, z;
};
```

---

¹ believe me, you *want* a library to diagnose this kind of situation

Answer (score 5):

Here's the result of my making it self contained.

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94bded442521b4c1)

I chose to adapt the VectorData type. (I noticed too late you probably didn't).

This makes the grammar over complicated. I'm not sure exactly *what* didn't work because well, by the time the code compiled it did work...

So let's make this another exercise in code cleanup and lead-by-example:

- removed semantic actions
- removed two rules
- added debug information
- removed the quirky required trailing `','` here:

  ```
  '{' >> repeat(_a)[ vertex_real_3d >> (',' | &lit('}')) ] >> '}'
  ```
- removed the redundant uses of `operator%=`
- removed the redundant uses of `qi::lit()`
- don't expose the `qi::locals<>` in the grammar declaration (it's an implementation detail)

Now the code clocks in at 77 lines (25 lines fewer than before):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cd678fa6df49de5)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

using long32  = int32_t;
using float32 = float;

namespace Geoset {
    template <typename T>
        struct Vertex3d {
            T a,b,c;
        };

    typedef Vertex3d<float32>       VertexData;
    typedef VertexData              VertexReal3d;
    typedef std::vector<VertexData> Vertices;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Geoset::VertexData, (float32, a)(float32, b)(float32, c))

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Geoset::Vertices(), Skipper> {

    grammar() : grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        vertex_real_3d = 
            '{' >> real_literal >> ','
                >> real_literal >> ','
                >> real_literal >> '}'
            ;

        vertices %=
                "Vertices"
                >> omit [ integer_literal[_a = _1] ]
                >> '{' >> repeat(_a)[ vertex_real_3d >> (',' | &lit('}')) ] >> '}'
            ;

        start = vertices;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(vertices)(vertex_real_3d))
    }
  private:
    qi::int_parser<long32> integer_literal;
    qi::real_parser<float32> real_literal;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Geoset::VertexReal3d(), Skipper> vertex_real_3d;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Geoset::Vertices(), Skipper, qi::locals<long32> > vertices;
    qi::rule<Iterator, Geoset::Vertices(), Skipper> start;
};

int main() {
    std::string const input = "Vertices 4 { \n"
        " { 1,  2,  3  }, \n"
        " { 4,  5,  6  }, \n"
        " { 7,  8,  9  }, \n"
        " { 10, 11, 12 } \n"
    "}";

    auto f(begin(input)), l(end(input));
    grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;

    Geoset::Vertices vertices;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,g,qi::space,vertices);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << vertices.size() << "\n";
        for (auto& v : vertices)
            std::cout << boost::fusion::as_vector(v) << "\n";
    } else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the comma does ALWAYS follow. Now, using your example does not explain why I cannot assign _1 of the repeat statement to _val which would be helpful to know.

Comment: Well well. A bit of a thankless job this is. I spent time trying to reproduce an error using a halfbaked code sample that you could have easily made self-contained. I explain that I sadly cannot answer your question, (because you failed to  provide the reproducer). You find the need to simultaneously dismiss the answer as "not explaining", and somehow still complain about a minor detail in my non-answer?

Comment: Regarding the comma business: "DON'T DO THAT THAN?". Solved. Note that nothing prohibits the comma anyhow. You had a real simple way to make me not doubt what the intention might be: _you could include sample input_. Do you realize I had to make that up myself? Do you realize that in fact "a comma always follows" is clearly not true, since the inner braces don't have the trailing commas...  Can you imagine why maybe I thought I might be doing you a favor by showing a way to make the last comma optional in the outer braces?

Comment: sry I did not mean to offend you with that "comma business". You made a great effort reproducing the code and well your example seems to work, so it must be something else than Spirit cannot handle the std::vector with repeat. I've added more code how the vertex class is adapted. It inherits std::array. Besides I've added the full error messages since I think it could help a Spirit expert.

Comment: @Baradé It's ok. I like it when people post questions in my particular hobby niche, so I tend to go the extra mile. I can't help but notice that your questions are often not up to par for [SO]. I later found that it's [not the first time](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20138281#20138281) I told you this.